# How do I create chapter lookup markings in the margins (like in a dictionary)?

Tags: sectioning, margins, thumb-index

I am creating a long collection of formulas that I would like to use as a printed reference. It already has a table of contents, but I would also like to add marks on the margin that allow for a quick lookup of the rough chapter. I am not sure how this is called, hence I hope the picture helps.

[image]

As can be seen, the margin contains (very) short abbreviations of all chapters on each page, with the current chapter highlighted. This is common in dictionaries and allows the reader to quickly flip to the correct page. Sometimes there is also only the current chapter marked on the margin, but for each chapter in a slightly shifted position.

Is this possible to implement in LaTeX and how would I do that? I am using `pdflatex` and the `article` class at the moment, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have a look if any post from https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/thumb-index/ might help you

Comment: @muxoveji Great, that helps very much! I used the `thumbs`package to make a simple version of this. Thanks!